# Android facebook login integration, user is null

Tags: facebook, integration, facebook-login, android

Following [this link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started), I created a sample application but control is not going into the if loop:

```
if(user!=null)
```

For debugging, I tried coding else part and display user not found.

**Expected Result:** It should have displayed hello *username*

**Actual Result:** It displays User not found

The complete code is as follows:

```
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {  
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);  
        Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);  
        Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {  

             public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {  
                if (session.isOpened()) {  
                    Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {  

                        public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {  
                            if (user != null) {  
                                TextView welcome = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.welcome);  
                                welcome.setText("Hello " + user.getName() + "!");
                            }  
                            else {
                                TextView welcome=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.welcome);  
                                welcome.setText("User not found");  
                            }
                        }  
                    }).executeAsync();  
                }  
            }  
        });  
    }
```

Surprisingly, it happens only on the emulator. On a real device, it is working fine

Comment: Put complete code here, cant figure out exact issue with just seeing one line of code..

Answer (score 0):

Having the same problem. Try this tutorial https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/login-with-facebook/v2.1

Basically, you have to implement UILifeCycle and get access to facebook user token, from which you can get necessary information.